# Recursively Search Through a Flat Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a flat, associative array that is being grepped for any elements that match a particular parentID. I then, however, need to re-run the function with the returned results to see if there are any elements with a parentID that match the previous result. Esentially, I am trying to get all children and children of those children.

In the array below, each element has a parent ID that matches it up with it's parent. I have a function that will grep the array for any elements that contain the parent ID that I pass to it, this works fine.

```
  array("id" => "Test", "parent" => "#", "text" => "Title"),
  array("id" => "Test1", "parent" => "Test", "text" => "Title1"),
  array("id" => "Test2", "parent" => "Test", "text" => "Title2"),
  array("id" => "Test3", "parent" => "Test2", "text" => "Title3") ,
  array("id" => "Test4", "parent" => "Test1", "text" => "Title4") ,
  array("id" => "Test5", "parent" => "Test1", "text" => "Title5") 


function getChildren(id){
  var children = jQuery.grep(orig, function( n, i ) {
   return ( n.parent === id );
  });
return children;

// var children = jQuery.grep(orig, function( n, i ) {
//     return ( n.parent === id );
//   });
//   $.each(children,function(a,b){
// 
//       getChildren(children[0]['id']);
//   });
}
```

After the function is run for the first time, it will return a list of children that contain that parent id. I now need to push all of those children back through the loop and get their children. Ideally, once the loop is finished, I would have a single array containing all children. Currently, the first part of the function works, but the area I commented out (where I try to pass the results back through) does not. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: From where the next syntax come from, `PHP`?:  `array("id" => "Test", "parent" => "#", "text" => "Title")`. Could you add the `Javascript` input you have? I guess you have an array of objects, but it is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7x9w4k0/2/),

```
function getChildren(id){
  let result = [];
  $.each(orig, function(i, d) {
     if (d.parent === id) {
            result.push(d);
        result.push(...getChildren(d.id));
     }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(getChildren('Test'));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!